# Update Auditing and Versioned Entity using JpaRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot application which has a simple Entity and JpaRepository and Service.

**Entity**:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    private String name;

    private String email;

}
```

**JpaRepository**:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

**Service**:

```
@Service
class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public User create(User user) {
        Assert.isNull(user.getId(), "Can't create an existing user!");
        return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public User update(User user) {
        Assert.notNull(user.getId(), "Can't update a new user!");
        return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
    }

}
```

> In my real application the `@Transactional` annotation is set in the `RestController` but `create()` and `update()` are never executed in the same transaction

When I create a new User like this:

```
User user = new User();
user.setName("user");
user.setEmail("user@email");
userService.create(user);
```

Spring automatically set all Auditing properties (created, lastModified, ...) and the version to 0.

But when I update an existing User like this:

```
User user = new User();
user.setId(1L);             // Id of the User I want to update
user.setVersion(5L)         // Current version is 5L
user.setName("user");  
user.setEmail("new@email"); // I want to update only the email
userService.update(user);
```

I get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "created" violates not-null constraint
```

which means that Spring auditing is not handling the `created` property.

To fix this I have changed my `update` method in the `UserService` in this way:

```
@Transactional
public User update(User user) {
    Assert.notNull(user.getId(), "Can't update a new user!");
    User original = userRepository.getOne(user.getId())
    original.setVersion(user.getVersion());
    original.setName(user.getName());
    original.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    return userRepository.saveAndFlush(original);
}
```

this fixed the `PSQLException` but then the version is not validated any more. Which means that if I set a version different to the current version in the database I don't get the `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` error, and the updated User is saved in the database without any error.

> I can substitute the `.getOne()` with `.findById()` but nothing change

At the end I have been able to fix both my problems int this way:

```
@Transactional
public User update(User user) {
    Assert.notNull(user.getId(), "Can't update a new user!");
    Assert.notNull(user.getVersion(), "Version must be defined!");
    User original = userRepository.getOne(user.getId())
    User update = new User();
    update.setId(original.getId());
    update.setCreated(original.getCreated());
    update.setCreatedBy(original.getCreatedBy());
    update.setVersion(user.getVersion());
    update.setName(user.getName());
    update.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    return userRepository.saveAndFlush(update);
}
```

> I still need to check that the version is not null otherwise the user will be saved without checking the version

now auditing fields don't throw `PSQLException` and version is verified before update and a `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` is throw when it is wrong.

But this solution is **awful**  because I need to copy properties left and right and in bigger entities it will be easy to forget something.

Do you know a better solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you confirm that that you've enabled the auditing framework via config, either xml or java  as per the documentation [here:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.DATAJPA-580-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/auditing.html) or you have the @EnableJpaAuditing applied to your spring config class

Comment: Yes and I have implemented an `AuditorAware` object for the user